# Where to point the server root in Wampserver - images not showing

Tags: php, apache, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using Wamp Server to view my files on Localhost.

All is fine, but I cannot see the images. I have changed the following code in Apache > httpd.config

```
ServerRoot "C:/wamp64/www/Myfolder/html/"

DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/Myfolder/html/"
```

the assets folder with my images is in a file called html.

However, I cannot see the images still.

Completely new to php so if anyone could please explain what or why this is not working for me that would be great.

Should I be typing something in the command window to make the changes of the server root and document root?

Using Bootstrap, Less, Grunt, Bower, Nodejs

Thanks

Comment: Please click on check mark if my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1: Add your images in the root folder "C:/wamp64/www/MyImages"

Step2: Start your wamp server & click on localhost on the browser http://127.0.0.1:9090 [should display the default wamp welcome page]

Step3: Append the image directory http://127.0.0.1:9090/MyImages/TestImg.png

The image should appear on the screen. Thats all.

Good luck & Hope it helps.

Comment: http://localhost/images/banner.png I can see the image if i type this, but I cannot see them when I load the site. Any tips? Thanks for your help

Comment: can you see the image in the browser as per the steps above? If yes, then it may due to some permissions on the folder where the images are stored.

Comment: yes I can, should I put telling it anywhere where the images are stored?

Comment: In what application are you trying to access those images? php? .Net? others?

Comment: I guess its nothing to do with the WampServer, its something to do with the code where your trying to access the image.

Comment: I still cannot get it to work. Can see the images if I just view them, but not when I look at the whole site.

Comment: Can you share the code from where your trying to access but cannot see the image?

Comment: sure I will put it in my question, from the index.php page? ie the homepage

Comment: <div id="logo" class="text-center">
            <a href="/"><img src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
        </div>
    </header>

Comment: Try to set the image height & width using css for the img tag.

Comment: If nothing works pls share a copy of your project folder including index.php & your images i'll troubleshoot on my machine [farhanshaikh02@outlook.com]